# jodd.json.jsonException while parsing a map Liferay post api

Tags: json, post, liferay, json-rpc

I'm trying to expose a post api with this signature, i need to get a map with String key and String value, same for the return:

```
public Map<String,String> retrieveBulkState2(Map<String,String> idsAndMails) throws PortalException{
```

I'm trying to call this endpoint from postman with this json payload (i can call all others api that don't involve a collection as a parameter):

```
{
    "method":"retrieve-bulk-state2",
    "params":{
        "idsAndMails":{
            "test3": "prova3",
            "test": "prova"
        }
    },
    "id":123,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

And i can't figure out why i get this parsing error, i tried multiple formatting styles and even trying to pass a simple List but seems like liferay can't parse the collections via json-rpc:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "error": {
        "code": -32603,
        "message": "jodd.json.JsonException: Syntax error! Invalid char: expected \"\noffset: 1 near: \"{test3=prov...\""
    },
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

If i try to pass an empty map all works fine.

Full stacktrace:

```
2022-03-21 19:47:54.065 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5][JSONWebServiceActionImpl:102] jodd.json.JsonException: Syntax error! Invalid char: expected "_offset: 1 near: "{test3=prov..." [Sanitized]
jodd.json.JsonException: Syntax error! Invalid char: expected "_offset: 1 near: "{test3=prov..." [Sanitized]
    at jodd.json.JsonParser.syntaxError(JsonParser.java:1012)
    at jodd.json.JsonParser.consume(JsonParser.java:927)
    at jodd.json.JsonParser.parseString(JsonParser.java:441)
    at jodd.json.JsonParser.parseObjectContent(JsonParser.java:827)
    at jodd.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:331)
    at jodd.json.JsonParser._parse(JsonParser.java:271)
    at jodd.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.json.JSONDeserializerImpl.deserialize(JSONDeserializerImpl.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.json.JSONFactoryImpl.looseDeserialize(JSONFactoryImpl.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil.looseDeserialize(JSONFactoryUtil.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceActionImpl._convertValueToParameterValue(JSONWebServiceActionImpl.java:344)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceActionImpl._prepareParameters(JSONWebServiceActionImpl.java:548)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceActionImpl._invokeActionMethod(JSONWebServiceActionImpl.java:498)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceActionImpl.invoke(JSONWebServiceActionImpl.java:97)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceServiceAction.getJSON(JSONWebServiceServiceAction.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.JSONAction.execute(JSONAction.java:75)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.JSONServlet.service(JSONServlet.java:63)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceServlet.service(JSONWebServiceServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.authverifier.AuthVerifierFilter.processFilter(AuthVerifierFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.lockout.LockoutFilter.processFilter(LockoutFilter.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:248)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
In the JSON rpc calll you should pass arguments like this:

```
{
    "method":"retrieve-bulk-state",
    "params":{
        "+idsAndMails":"java.util.HashMap",
        "idsAndMails.key1":"value1",
        "idsAndMails.key2":"value2"
    },
    "id":123,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

In this way the json parser of Liferay will know that needs to handle a map, weird but that's what we have.